# Правила iptables для openvpn-клиента

Tags: linux, iptables

Добрый день, коллеги!
Прошу помощи с настройкой iptables.
Дано: Удалённый сервер с двумя сетевыми картами и VPN-подключением.

1. eth1 - Внешняя сеть (Смотрит в интернет)
2. eth2 - Внутренняя сеть (Смотрит в DMZ)
3. tap0 - VPN (Смотрит на vpn-сервер через eth1).

Никак не получается прописать правила iptables так, чтобы продолжал работать vpn (Openvpn).

Текущие правила:

```
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -s адрес_офиса/32 -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport Хитрый_Порт -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth1 -s 8.8.8.8 -p udp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth1 -d 8.8.8.8 -p udp --sport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth1 -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tap0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tap0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tap0 -o eth1 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o tap0 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tap0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport Хитрый_Порт -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tap0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10050 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tap0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10051 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tap0 -p udp -m udp --dport 10050 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tap0 -p udp -m udp --dport 10051 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth1 -j DROP
-A INPUT -i eth2 -j DROP
```

При включении iptables на vpn интерфейсе перестают ходить пинги, но интерфейс не падает. Подключение на Хитрый_Порт тоже закрыто.

Если я делаю -A INPUT -i eth1 -j ACCEPT, то всё работает, но это не вариант.
В чём я ошибся?

p.s. zabbix использует tcp или udp на портах 10050/51?

---

Сам себе дал ответ, но... Он не заработал. Точнее, сначала заработал, а потом опять перестали ходить пакеты. Добавление `-A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1194 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT` не помогло.

Comment: А зачем так сложно, не проще для IP-адреса vpn сервера просто все разрешить. И Хитрый_порт он на какой стороне ? на вашей или того сервера. Если того сервера, то на input у вас будут ответные пакеты от него, т.е. `-s хитрый-порт`. И что за vpn у вас, ему одного порта хватает ? А то вдруг какой нибудь pptp, которому кроме 1723 порта tcp подавай еще 47 ip-протокол

Comment: Нет, из vpn-подсети должны быть доступны только Хитрый_Порт, ssh и zabbix-agent. Сервер vpn - openvpn. Думал, ему 1194 будет достаточно. Возможно как-то неправильно форвардинг сделал. Хитрый порт у меня на стороне этого сервера, т.е. в этом случае точно dport

Comment: тогда запускайте tcpdump и смотрите какие пакеты реально приходят с ip-адреса vpn и на какие порты.

Comment: @Mike, если делаю так: -A INPUT -s ХостНэймВпнСервера -i eth1 -j ACCEPT То всё работает. Но это не есть правильно =)

Comment: прочитал про openvpn, да, судя по всему ему 1 порт нужен. Только там еще что то про udp говорится. вы все таки `tcpdump -n -i eth1 host адрес-vpn` сделайте, посмотрите что реально он шлет и что из этого об стенку разбивается

Comment: Ну, у меня, собственно, udp 1194 как раз и открыт.

Comment: @Mike Однако tcpdump ничего не ловит от vpn-сервера по tcp. Занятно.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. Я сам себе злобный буратино. Но и с openvpn не всё так просто.

Клиент при подключении обращается действительно на порт 1194 сервера openvpn. А, вот, destinaton порт на клиенте назначается в момент подключения. Для каждого клиента сервер назначает свой udp-порт и передает данные уже через него. Кстати, найти в мануале openvpn destination port-range мне не удалось.

Но при этом source порт у пакетов с vpn-сервера действительно 1194 udp. Так что меня спасла строчка:

```
-A INPUT -i eth1 -p udp -m udp --sport 1194 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Форварды и прочее оказались не нужны для клиента. Так что конфиг выглядит следующим образом:

```
-A INPUT -s Адрес_Офиса/32 -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport Хитрый_Порт -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s Адрес_Офиса/32 -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth1 -s 8.8.8.8 -p udp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth1 -d 8.8.8.8 -p udp --sport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth1 -p udp -m udp --sport 1194 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tap0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport Хитрый_Порт -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tap0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10050 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tap0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10051 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tap0 -p udp -m udp --dport 10050 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tap0 -p udp -m udp --dport 10051 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth1 -j DROP
-A INPUT -i eth2 -j DROP
-A INPUT -i tap0 -j DROP
```